# How to use Sitecore API key in conjunction with retrieving an item

Tags: rest, postman, sitecore9

I am attempting to make a request to our `Sitecore9` instance with `Postman`:

Method:

```
POST
```

URL:

```
https://{{sitecorehost}}/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

Body:

```
{
    "domain": "sitecore",
    "username": "{{sitecoreusername}}",
    "password": "{{sitecorepassword}}"
}
```

In `Postman` this returns a `403`, though I can easily login to the `Sitecore` instance with the URL provided in my `Postman` environment variables.

I have been provided an `apikey` by the site admin but [the authentication documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html#idm46403424117760) does not appear to specify how this should be used or if I need to pass it in conjunction with the authentication values.

The [documentation which does describe using an apikey](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-odata-item-service.html#UUID-c38dc080-d839-9d83-f853-69ffcddddf2f_id_api-keys-usage) also describes [retrieving an item using it's GUID](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-odata-item-service.html#idm46403424342848) but when I request this in `Postman` like this:

Method:

```
GET
```

URL:

```
https://{{sitecorehost}}/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('{5AB4C9A0-5889-4F50-9D7F-D960A1015FA7}')?sc_apikey={{sitecoreapikey}}
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

All I get is a `500 Internal Server Error` with this in the `body` of the response:

```
"message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
```

Comment: Is your PostMan login post request also giving a error? or what does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different type of API keys in Sitecore,
For Sitecore 9.0, you need to create a "**OData Item API Key**" from template   /sitecore/templates/System/Services/OData Item API Key and not "API Key" in the core database below /sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys/

Also you need to fill in Database in your API key, you can use value **web** 
likely this is your issue if you leave it empty you get the Error **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** in Sitecore 9.0

For AllowedControllers you can use value *

For Using Postman with login, 
After the login you get a cookie you need to use that in your getitem request.
you can [Download following Postman tool export file](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Services%20Layer/Play%20with%20Item%20Services/) as Example.